# Azure kubernetes - Prometheus to handle multiple applications

Tags: azure, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, azure-aks

I am planning to deploy 15 different applications initially and would endup with 300+ applications on azure kubernetes and would be using Prometheus and Grafana for monitoring.

I have deployed both the Prometheus and Grafana on a separate namespace on the dedicated node.

How do I enable horizontal pod scaling for Prometheus and Grafana?

Comment: Are you going to use Prometheus custom metrics for your HPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale your applications based on [custom metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/custom-metrics-api.md) gathered by Prometheus and presented in the Grafana dashboard.

In order to do that you'll need the [Prometheus Adapter](https://github.com/DirectXMan12/k8s-prometheus-adapter#prometheus-adapter-for-kubernetes-metrics-apis) to implement the custom metrics API, which enables the `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` controller to retrieve metrics using the `custom.metrics.k8s.io` API. You can define your own metrics through the adapter’s configuration so the HPA would scale based on those stats.

[Here](https://www.section.io/blog/horizontal-pod-autoscaling-custom-metrics/) you can find a short guide that would get you started.

Comment: How do I enable horizontal pod scaling for Prometheus and Grafana?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar You can use the [kubectl autoscale](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#autoscale) command for your Prometheus and Grafana Deployment, ReplicaSet, StatefulSet, or ReplicationController. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) you can find a walkthrough with more details and examples.